# Intellij limit the scope of search/find to current method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-idea-2016

I know by clicking on variable name Intellij **highlights references** to that local variable inside a method.

On so many occasions I want to *find(Ctrl+F)* a string(other than variable name) i.e think of

- string inside log stmt
- substring of variable name
- substring of other method name -calls from inside the  method you are in

I would like to limit the scope of this search/find inside the method I am working in.

However, **Intellij takes me to another method(matching the search string) inside the same class** and I loose the location of the method I was working on. I have to do Back(Ctrl+Alt+Left) to back to the method I was in. Doing this 100's of times a day is rather unproductive and I loose focus.

**Is there a way/intellij action to limit the scope of your search/find to the method you are in instead of the whole class.**

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible.

But you can click "All" button:

[image]

then expand your method in "Find:" tab in bottom left corner(by default).

Comment: nice hack but I wish Intellij created something to avoid so many clicks(navigating in tabs) to get to what you are looking for with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "find in selection" feature. Unfortunately this is only available for Replace, not for Find. Here's how to use it:

- Use the `Extend Selection` action to grow your selection to the entire method
- Invoke Replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (this will automatically have the `in selection` checkbox enabled
- Type the string you want to find

The locations of that string will be highlighted in the selection and you can navigate between the occurrences in the usual way.

Comment: Still works to find the search word with in the limit the scope of search to "find in selection".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The closest solution I've found is to use ctrl-shift-alt-j (select all occurrences) to highlight all occurrences of the selected text in a nice bold colour. It's then pretty easy to spot other uses of the string within the method.

Comment: this hack has a small issue where if your searched string is used in other methods, it will take you to the last occurrence of the match( which might be in different method).

Comment: This suggestion doesn't take you anywhere. It just highlights to matches so you can easily spot them.